# Postgres Write Ahead Logs - when Foreign Data Tables are updates, does Postgres write to the WAL?

Tags: postgresql, wal

I need to understand if Postgres writes to the the WAL for a Foreign Data Table. I'm looking to implement CDC and it triggers off write to the WAL. My understanding is that Foreign Data Tables are created in a schema - so I wouldn't expect Postgres to write to the WAL for these tables.

Any thoughts?

Comment: "created in a schema" has nothing to do with WAL. **Everything** in Postgres is create "in a schema". You can't have tables, views or other things outside of a schema. The WAL written will happen on the remove server though, not on the one where the foreign table is defined

Comment: I doubt it but I'd ask at Postgresql's mailing lists.